# C# RichTextBox selection problem

Tags: c#, controls

I have a RichTextBox control on an application and here's my problem: when the application runs, if I start selecting with the mouse some of the characters inside a word and continue selecting outside it, the selection automatically includes the whole word in which I begun selection and any other words from which I want to select just a part, ms word-ish, if I'm not mistaken.

e.g.:

- the text is:               "Just another foobar"
- what I want to select is:  "Just ano[ther foo]bar" (the thing between the [])
- what is actually selected: "Just [another foobar]"

The problem is just with mouse selecting, if I select text with the keyboard it works just fine. Also, the auto word select property of the control is turned off. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Hrm.  Was this fixed?  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115441/richtextboxs-autowordselection-property-does-not-work-correctly

Comment: Hmm...I think that's it. Have any idea of a workaround?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a silly bug in the AutoWordSelection property implementation.  The workaround is equally silly.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the existing RTB.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class FixedRichTextBox : RichTextBox {
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (!base.AutoWordSelection) {
            base.AutoWordSelection = true;
            base.AutoWordSelection = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I left an annotation at the bottom of this [MSDN Library page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.autowordselection%28VS.90%29.aspx) with the details of the bug.

Comment: That was totally lame...but thanks, I'll try it asap. I finally get to experience some of the .net bugs!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe things have changed since this question was answered, but I have an even simpler solution:

Just add `richTextBox1.AutoWordSelection = false;` to the code.

Sounds crazy, but setting this to `false` in the properties-box does not work.
You have to do it in the code, even if the property is already false.
Then it works!