# Mouse selection too smart -- gets more than the text I want

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox. When I select words in the text box, the text actually selected jumps to include other characters that I have not moved the mouse over.

This is particularly annoying when I have XML in my text box. I try to grab the beginning tag, and Windows (or the RichTextBox control) also grabs the close angle-bracket tag from the previous tag.

Is there a setting on the RichTextBox control or in my application that I can set that will turn off this too-smart behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# RichTextBox selection problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678620/c-richtextbox-selection-problem)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Hans. I'll try the solution in the other thread on Monday, and will report back. (Note that I don't have AutoWordSelection turned on, so I'll have to wait and see).

Comment: The solution at the link that Hans Passant referenced fixed this problem also.  Thanks, Hans!

Comment: Should Hans or I add a solution, or does this question get closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the "RichTextBox Selection problem" described in [C# RichTextBox selection problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678620/c-richtextbox-selection-problem) also solved my issue.

I think the question I asked should remain to help others find the correct solution.

Thanks, Hans for pointing me to the solution.