# RichTextBox selection bug when pressing control key

Tags: c#, richtextbox, selection

I have a very strange bug with text selection in *RichTextBox* :

I create the following simple form :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret victura dum erunt homines Roma, ut augeretur sublimibus incrementis, foedere pacis aeternae Virtus convenit atque Fortuna plerumque dissidentes, quarum si altera defuisset, ad perfectam non venerat summitatem.";
    }
}
```

When launching the app I can select the text in the *RichTextBox* until I press the control key.

The *RichTextBox* is then no longer selectable until I click several times outside the application.

I hear about [silly bug with AutoWordSelection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678620/c-sharp-richtextbox-selection-problem) but I tried the trick without success.

I'm using *Framework .Net v4* on *Windows 8*.

Does anyone have an idea about it?

Comment: The Control key plus the arrow key just jumps to the beginning of the next word.  Can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you on the same OS/Framework version?

Comment: Yes, same Framework / OS.

Comment: Same here.  You have .NET v4.5 btw.  This is an environmental problem, if you use a trackpad then look there first.

Comment: I use a regular mouse.

Comment: Is this the whole form or are there any other components that could cause this strange behavior? Are there maybe any other events activ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see what is selected when the control button is clicked. (Maybe another application that is running?)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your form load event.

`RichTextBox1.AutoWordSelection = False`

this is reputed to be a 'will not fix' feature so you have to deactivate behaviour I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Mybe put the text outside the application.
works good for me

```
    private void CleaningManual_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RichTB.LoadFile(@"C:\awTextFiles\CleaningManual.rtf");
    }
```