# Win Forms: RichText Box -> AutoWordSelection/Hide Selection bug

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I think I've encountered a bug in .NET, but I would like to know if that's not something wrong I do.

First of all, I am creating simple text editor in Win Forms. I've added the functionality to find a desired text. It works as a modeless dialog that I've created. I wanted it to work like this: if the searched word is found, it selects the text in RTB, give focus to it, and then give focus back to my modeless window. In connection with enabling Hide Selection property it worked perfectly, exactly as I wanted it to be (the focus was still on modeless window after searching, but found phrase was remaining highlighted in RTB).

Later on, I've noticed that there's something wrong with AutoWordSelection property, it just didn't work. So I've did as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678620/c-sharp-richtextbox-selection-problem#comment3873783_3678620). And indeed, it helped, but then I've noticed that my searching algorithm doesn't work (now I need to give focus to RTB after searching and not give it back to modeless window). In other words it just stopped working.

I was trying to add some code in my FixedRichTextBox (I just added it under the first part suggested by Hans):

```
if(base.HideSelection)
    base.HideSelection=false;
base.HideSelection=false;
```

I also tried it the other way, I mean : `if(!baseSelection) [...]

In both cases, I got the message about not possibility to create window handle. Thus, I would have to agree to live only with AutoWordSelection or HideSelection working correctly (cause above part is working if I remove the earlier part concering AutoWordSelection).

This is not a very serious problem, as I've found a way to make it work just a little bit not as I want it to be (but it doesn't restrict the functionality of an application). However, this bug (if it's a bug) is annoying and I would like to know if anyone ever experienced that and found a proper solution.

Let's say @Hans Passant :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So it seems like I've found the answer to it (which is obvious cause I've posted it here). In this case, it was neccessary to do exactly as in the post I linked in a question, then set the HideSelection to true (in mainForm.cs), and set it to false programatically in a public ctor. Quite stupid but it works now (and it does NOT if I set this to false by default).