# why all text gets selected in RichTextBox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I only have form1 with RichTextBox (windows form) and I have no code.

Lets say we write "123456789" in RichTextBox via the keyboard.
The problem is:  when I try to select number 9 from right to left by using the mouse then the whole text get selected automatically before even I select the rest of the text.

But I CAN select 9 from left to right without the rest of text gets selected. And also I CAN select number 1 from right to left and without the rest of text gets selected. The problem happens only when you select the last number from right to left.

you can select any number from right to left and the rest of the text does not get selected but if you select the last number from right to left then the whole text gets selected.

I checked the RichTextBox properties but nothing interesting there. TexBox does not behave like this but I do not want to use textbox.

My question is: How can I select number 9 from right to left in RichTextBox using mouse and avoid the whole text from being selected automatically. Thank you

Comment: Actually I can't select the last character from the right __either__.

Comment: here is simply solution which given by Henrik Eriksen.  add richTextBox1.AutoWordSelection = false; on form load and it works. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer given by Hans Passant, all credit goes to him.
(At this point I feel that giving him more rep is like taking a p*ss into Niagra Falls)

[C# RichTextBox selection problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678620/c-sharp-richtextbox-selection-problem)

In Hans' words:

> There's a silly bug in the AutoWordSelection property implementation. The workaround is equally silly. Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below. Compile. Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the existing RTB.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class FixedRichTextBox : RichTextBox {
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (!base.AutoWordSelection) {
            base.AutoWordSelection = true;
            base.AutoWordSelection = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I could definitely replicate this behaviour before, and the custom RichTextBox fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you Equalsk. I am sorry I am new to C#. I added new class and pasted your code on it but the RichTextBox word and the method OnHandleCreated are both underlined with red which indicates there is something else I have to declare . any idea? thank you

Comment: okay I found another simpler solution: add richTextBox1.AutoWordSelection = false; on form load and it works. thank you

Comment: As long as you don't want automatic word selection, then I guess that's great. Glad it works.