# vb.net - Disable word selection in a richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, selection, richtextbox

I need a way to disable full-word selection in a RichTextBox.

Here's my problem: I want to create a text-editing application that can have images in the text. However, I have noticed that when selecting text in a RichTextBox, you can only select a full word.

*NOTE: Just in case it's system-based, I'm using VS 2015 on Windows 10*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN, it seems there's a bug with AutoWordSelection in RichTextBox. To fix it, just make a Timer, set Enabled to True, and in the event, write the following code:

```
RichTextBox1.AutoWordSelection = True
RichTextBox1.AutoWordSelection = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work for me but the following one does:

[C# RichTextBox selection problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678620/c-sharp-richtextbox-selection-problem)

Here is [Telerik's](http://converter.telerik.com/) attempt to a C# to VB.NET conversion:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
    If Not MyBase.AutoWordSelection Then
        MyBase.AutoWordSelection = True
        MyBase.AutoWordSelection = False
    End If
End Sub
```