# C# RichTextBox disable auto block selection

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I can't make partial selection for text in RichTextBox, how to disable the auto selection?

[image]

```
this.txtMSInput = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
this.txtMSInput.DetectUrls = false;
this.txtMSInput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 31);
this.txtMSInput.Name = "txtMSInput";
this.txtMSInput.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(279, 202);
this.txtMSInput.TabIndex = 43;
this.txtMSInput.Text = "";
```

Comment: why downvote? should I post VS2017 generated code for this RichTextBox?

Comment: Yes. I wasn't the downvote, but please show what you have attempted so far, and we can help from there.

Comment: @DylanCorriveau I have tell it, it just default generated code for RTB everyone who use VS must be know the code but btw I posted the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, this is RichTextBox bug.

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3679036/10767810

> There's a silly bug in the AutoWordSelection property implementation.
>   The workaround is equally silly. Add a new class to your project and
>   paste the code shown below. Compile. Drop the new control from the top
>   of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the existing RTB.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class FixedRichTextBox : RichTextBox {
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (!base.AutoWordSelection) {
            base.AutoWordSelection = true;
            base.AutoWordSelection = false;
        }
    }
}
```

> I left an annotation at the bottom of this MSDN Library page with the details of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on the project I am working with. I had a previous version that was working but a new one didn't. You just need to override the form OnLoad and set the AutoWordSelection to false there.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    rtfQuery.AutoWordSelection = false;
}
```